# Lists not being added to quicklaunch

Tags: feature, custom-list, site-definition

I'm having a problem with some lists that are included in a feature (Scope: web), which is created via a site definition.

These lists have the display on quicklaunch set to true, although, the only element that is added is the "Lists" header (level 0 node). The name of these lists is not added below the "Lists" header.

How can I add each of these lists to the quicklaunch?

Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<List xmlns:ows="Microsoft SharePoint" Title="Emprestimos" FolderCreation="FALSE" Direction="$Resources:Direction;" Url="Lists/Emprestimos" BaseType="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <MetaData>
<ContentTypes>


<ContentType ID="0x0100778bc246ea6046b8a4b1cabf87702c77" Name="ListFieldsContentType"><FieldRefs><FieldRef ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" Name="Title" /><FieldRef ID="{16608644-1a00-4c87-af9d-c946923a69b6}" Name="Telefone" /><FieldRef ID="{b9f2fee9-5dcc-4eba-b013-5b005057cfdb}" Name="ItemDocumental" /><FieldRef ID="{1c43319f-536d-44d5-8d37-a6dbe7792e41}" Name="DataEntrega" /></FieldRefs></ContentType><ContentTypeRef ID="0x01">
    <Folder TargetName="Item" />
  </ContentTypeRef><ContentTypeRef ID="0x0120" /></ContentTypes>
<Fields>

<Field ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" Type="Text" Name="Title" DisplayName="$Resources:core,Title;" Required="TRUE" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="Title" MaxLength="255" /><Field Name="Telefone" ID="{16608644-1a00-4c87-af9d-c946923a69b6}" DisplayName="Telefone" Type="Number" /><Field Name="ItemDocumental" ID="{b9f2fee9-5dcc-4eba-b013-5b005057cfdb}" DisplayName="Item documental" Type="LookupMulti" List="PlanoArquivo" Mult="TRUE" /><Field Name="DataEntrega" ID="{1c43319f-536d-44d5-8d37-a6dbe7792e41}" DisplayName="Data de entrega" Type="DateTime" Format="DateOnly" /></Fields>
<Views>


<View BaseViewID="0" Type="HTML" MobileView="TRUE" TabularView="FALSE">
    <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
    <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
    <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
    <ViewFields>

    <FieldRef Name="LinkTitleNoMenu"></FieldRef></ViewFields>
    <Query>
      <OrderBy>

      <FieldRef Name="Modified" Ascending="FALSE"></FieldRef></OrderBy>
    </Query>
    <ParameterBindings>
      <ParameterBinding Name="AddNewAnnouncement" Location="Resource(wss,addnewitem)" />
      <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_LIST)" />
      <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_ONET_HOME)" />
    </ParameterBindings>
  </View><View BaseViewID="1" Type="HTML" WebPartZoneID="Main" DisplayName="$Resources:core,objectiv_schema_mwsidcamlidC24;" DefaultView="TRUE" MobileView="TRUE" MobileDefaultView="TRUE" SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/generic.png" Url="AllItems.aspx">
    <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
    <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
    <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
    <ViewFields>


    <FieldRef Name="Attachments"></FieldRef><FieldRef Name="LinkTitle"></FieldRef><FieldRef Name="Telefone" /><FieldRef Name="ItemDocumental" /><FieldRef Name="DataEntrega" /></ViewFields>
    <Query>
      <OrderBy>

      <FieldRef Name="ID"></FieldRef></OrderBy>
    </Query>
    <ParameterBindings>
      <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_LIST)" />
      <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_DEFAULT)" />
    </ParameterBindings>
  </View></Views>
<Forms>
  <Form Type="DisplayForm" Url="DispForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
  <Form Type="EditForm" Url="EditForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
  <Form Type="NewForm" Url="NewForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
</Forms>
  </MetaData>
</List>
```

Instance Elements.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
<ListInstance Title="Empréstimos" OnQuickLaunch="TRUE" TemplateType="10015" Url="Lists/Emprestimos" Description="My List Instance"></ListInstance>
</Elements>
```

Comment: A good start would be to submit you list creation code for us to look over! :)

Comment: @RobertLindgren the list is created via XML (code added to the original message)

Comment: I'm failing to find a list instance in your XML

Comment: The list instance is in another file, I'll add its code too.

Comment: Are both in the same feature? Otherwise you need to specify FeatureId in the list instance

Comment: Other than that I see no errors at a glance

Comment: Yes. Same Feature.